# Tensorflow, tf.train.slice_input_producer returns empty tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new in TensorFlow. I try to make queues from 2 separated files. But it returns empty tensor. 
Here is sample code.

```
    flow_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(a.input_dir, "*.flo"))
    input_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(a.input_dir, "*.png"))

    inputs_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(input_paths, dtype=tf.string)
    flows_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(flow_paths, dtype=tf.string)
    path_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([inputs_t, flows_t],  shuffle=True)
```

In this code, tf.train.slice_input_producer returns empty tensor. Anything wrong to use input pipeline? flow_paths and input paths are string list.